# I want to get input from the user in Erlang and add it to the database

Tags: sql, erlang

```
insert(Id, Country, Province, City, Street, PostCode) ->
  odbc:start(), 
  {ok,Seve} = odbc:connect("DSN=test", []),
  io:fwrite("~p", odbc:param_query(Seve,"INSERT INTO Address (ID, COUNTRY, 
                  PROVINCE, CITY, STREET, POST_CODE) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

I want to get input from the user in Erlang and add it to the database.

Now where do I use the values taken at the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take the user of input use following function.

```
{ok, Input} = io:read("Enter a params: ").
```

Edit,
Make sure Params' input is like [1,3,4,...]

```
odbc:param_query(Seve,"INSERT INTO Address (ID, COUNTRY, 
                  PROVINCE, CITY, STREET, POST_CODE) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", Params).
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't get the output
Gives the following error.

Comment: Enter a params: [1,ccccc,ppp,ccc,sss,123].
** exception error: no function clause matching 
                    odbc:param_query(<0.260.0>,
                                     "INSERT INTO Address (ID, COUNTRY, \n                  PROVINCE, CITY, STREET, POST_CODE) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                                     {ok,[1,ccccc,ppp,ccc,sss,123]},
                                     infinity) (odbc.erl, line 366)

Comment: "INSERT INTO Address (ID, COUNTRY, \n PROVINCE, CITY, STREET, POST_CODE) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [1,ccccc,ppp,ccc,sss,123], infinity) is correct